# Setting up RevenueCat Purchases in ReactNative throws "NativeModule" cannot be null error

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-ios, revenuecat

I have followed the installation instructions and got the project to build successfully. Now, when I import Purchases in my javascript code I get the exception "Native module cannot be null".

[image: Native module cannot be null error]

The `NativeModules` object imported from `react-native` does not have the `RNPurchases` module that the required by `react-native-purchases`.

**System**

XCode 10
MacOS Mojave
React Native 0.50.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the built binary of the `RNPurchases` subproject is not automatically linked to the project.

1. Go to the `General` tab in your project's target
2. Click `+` in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`
3. Add `libRNPurchases.a`